# Algorithm for queue with multiple repeated different interval events

Tags: algorithms

I have N events, each repeats after some time t<sub>i</sub>. I want a queue where I can pop out next event.

For example, I have events A,B,C with intervals 2,3,5 At the beginning they all are in the queue with values:

A-2, B-3, C-5

When I take out event, it should be A, after that I put it back, but add +2.

B-3, A-4, C-5

Next is B. I add +3

A-4, C-5, B-6

Next is A, I add +2

C-5, B-6, A-6

and so on.

What could be the best algorithm for that?

Comment: Have you considered using a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)?

Comment: Yes, priority queue was my first option, but my intuitions says that there should be something better.

Comment: "Best"/"better" by what metric?  Running time?  Implementation complexity?  Something else?  "Best" is subjective, so it's not clear what you're looking for.  (Also, what research have you done?)

Answer (score 2):

Use an efficient implementation of [priority queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), such as [binary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). Then, your algorithm would look like this:

```
proc triggerEvents(events : Array[(String, Integer)]) {
  q = new MinHeap()
  for ( i=0; i<events.size; i++ ) {
    // use event index as key, interval as priority
    q.add(i, events[i][2])
  }

  while ( true ) {
    (i, p) = q.popMin()
    trigger(events[i][1])
    q.add(i, p + events[i][2])
  }
}
```

With $n$ the number of events, this will take time $\Theta(n \log n)$ for the initialisation¹ and then $O(\log n)$ time for each iteration of the `while` loop plus whatever `trigger` does.

In practice, be mindful of overflows.

You can not be asymoptotically faster than that; otherwise we could sort² in time $o(n \log n)$ which is not possible (for unrestricted inputs).

---

1. Can be sped up to $O(n)$; see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap).
2. Add one event per element with its value as time interval. Drop the re-adding from the algorithm and execute $n$ iterations of the `while`-loop. Trigger just prints the element.

Comment: You can do better than $O(\log n)$ per iteration, but it requires a long processing time. The events will start repeating after the LCM of the times, so you could precompute everything up to that point to achieve $O(1)$  per iteration. But this is only worth it if you have many, many iterations.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Huh. That would suggest that my lower bound argument is false, at least. Well, my bounds don't include the number $M$ of "read" events. If $M > n$ we no longer have random permutation. Your solution gives us something of the form $\Theta(M + f(n))$, right? (Nitpick: "better than $O(\log n)$" has little meaning; you mean $o(\log n)$?)

Comment: That's correct. With regards to your nitpick I guess you meant $\Omega$ rather than $o$? ;-) I don't think there's anything wrong with what I wrote, though $\Omega$ may have been more precise. A $O(1)$ algorithm is better than a $O(\log n)$ algorithm - even though they may have the same running time you have a stronger guarantee about the former one.

Comment: "Faster than $\Omega(\_)$" or just "$o(\_)$", yes. "A O(1) algorithm is better than a O(logn) algorithm" -- if "better" means something like "<" in runtime, this is simply a non sequitur, because of the formal definitions. I know many use $O$ that way, but it's confusing at best and probably harmful to do so. "A is smaller than at most B" just does not tell you anything. If you (general you) mean $\Theta$, or $\Omega$, or $o$, just use the appropriate symbols instead of ambiguous language.